# Pandas: Access timestamp attributes after reindex

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am having trouble understanding what happens to a timestamp after you reindex a data frame using `pd.date_range`.  If I have the following example where I am using `pd.DataFrame.reindex` to create a longer time series:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

idx_inital = pd.date_range('2004-03-01','2004-05-05')

df = pd.DataFrame(index = idx_inital, data={'data': np.random.randint(0,100,idx_inital.size)})

idx_new = pd.date_range('2004-01-01','2004-05-05')

df= df.reindex(idx_new, fill_value = 0)
```

which returns the expected result where all data are assigned `0`:

```
            data
2004-01-01     0
2004-01-02     0
2004-01-03     0
2004-01-04     0
2004-01-05     0
```

Now If I want to use apply to assign a new column using:

```
def year_attrib(row):
    if row.index.month >2:
        result = row.index.year + 11
    else:
        result = row.index.year + 15
    return result

df['year_attrib'] = df.apply(lambda x: year_attrib(x), axis=1)
```

I am getting the error:

```
AttributeError: ("'Index' object has no attribute 'month'", 'occurred at index 2004-01-01 00:00:00')
```

If I inspect what each row is being passed to `year_attrib` with:

```
row = df.iloc[0]
row
Out[32]: 
data    0
Name: 2004-01-01 00:00:00, dtype: int32
```

It looks like the timestamp is being passed to `Name` and I have no idea how to access it.  When I look at `row.index` I get:

```
row.index
Out[34]: Index(['data'], dtype='object')
```

What is the cause of this behavior?

Comment: `df['year_attrib']=np.where(df.index.month>2,22,11)` you dont need a func for this

Comment: @anky_91 Ahh, I made it too simple.  I have revised to func to return a value based on `row.index.year`

Comment: same `np.where(df.index.month>2,df.index.year+11,df.index.year+15)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is, when use `apply` function to a `DataFrame` with parameter `axis=1`, each row of the dataframe is passed to the function as a `Series`. See the [doc of pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

So, what actually happened in the `year_attrib` function is, `row.index` will return the index of the `row`, which is the `column` of the dataframe.

```
In [5]: df.columns
Out[5]: Index(['data'], dtype='object')
```

thus `AttributeError` will be raised when use `row.index.month`.

if you really want to use this function to get what you want, use `row.name.month` instead.

however it's still suggested to use a `vectorized` way, like:

```
In [10]: df.loc[df.index.month>2, 'year_attrib'] = df[df.index.month>2].index.year + 11

In [11]: df.loc[df.index.month<=2, 'year_attrib'] = df[df.index.month>2].index.year + 15

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
            data  year_attrib
2004-03-01    93         2015
2004-03-02    48         2015
2004-03-03    88         2015
2004-03-04    44         2015
2004-03-05    11         2015
2004-03-06     4         2015
2004-03-07    70         2015
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I knew each row is passed as a series, that's why I started looking at the series `df.iloc[0]`.  I had tried looking for `row.Name` instead of `row.name` as you pointed out.  Its a bit misleading when you look at `print(row)` where the n in capitalized in Name.  I have a better understanding now of how apply works.  Cheers!

Comment: yes, you are doing right. I misundstood the last part of the question :-( . and BTW you can use dir(row) to see how to access Name meyhod.

Comment: Just tried running the `df.loc` lines I am getting:  `ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (126,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (66,)`.  From the looks of your example, you are showing `df`  before it eas reindexed.

Comment: err, yes, I forgot. see the modified answer.